# Fetch values from HTML files to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, microsoft-edge

I have multiple HTML files in my folder. I need to fetch some data from each html files and copy those value in excel sheet using VBA MACRO. how to write code to achieve this?.

And the html files should open in Microsoft edge browser (not in IE)

If any one knows the solution please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using Selenium? Edge cannot do all the things that IE could do.

Answer (score 0):

You said,'**the HTML files should open in Microsoft Edge browser (not in IE)**'.

If your goal is to copy the data to an Excel sheet then I think it should not matter whether you are doing it via IE or Edge.

If you are thinking that as IE browser is retired on some Windows OS and your IE VBA Automation will not work then I would like to inform you that IE VBA automation will continue to work even after the IE browser retirement.

If you still want to automate the Edge browser then as suggested by the community member, you will need to use the [web driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

For VBA IE Automation the general idea would be to create an object of the IE or Edge browser from the Excel VBA editor. Launch the browser. Browse the web page. browse to the web element and copy the data to the Excel sheet.

If you use Selenium then you also need to use the library for Excel and create an object of the Excel file.

For more information, you could refer to the links below.

1. [Use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp)
2. [Automate Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp#automate-microsoft-edge)

Similar kinds of articles and docs you could find for the IE VBA Automation.

You could refer to the docs and try to make tests on your side. If you are stuck somewhere or have any questions. you could post a new question on this forum.